# Areas Routing in MVC 4 with angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Let me define my setup here. I have some areas like 1. AreaA 2. AreaB 3. AreaC and 4. AreaGeneral. in AreaGeneral I have one controller as home and GetData(paras) and it returns some data either in partial or full page form to angularjs. If I am using these two controller inside the AreaGeneral then its ok. but I want to provide the same controllers inside other Areas like in A, B, and AreaC, but there area and route are different. and more importantly when a user navigates to particular area say AreaB to access GetData(paras) controller then the url should be like .../AreaB/GetData instead of .../AreaGeneral/GetData and the route should work in other areas as well. Can someone guide me how to do this, Thanks.

Comment: GetData is a routable action? It would probably make more sense to have the various controllers call the same action via ajax or have them inherit the action from a BaseController class.

Comment: can you please be more clear on this, or better explain me how I can accomplish this. or an example will be better

Comment: I'm not sure I could figure out exactly what you're trying to do without examples of your controller code / area structure.

Comment: like I explained above, I have multiple areas in my app, and If I have to create a report/form in one area then if my application demands the same report/form to be available in another area then I have to redesign it(or copy paste which I dont want duplication). Instead of that can I make the same already defined controller from that area to any other area by reflecting the url name to the same area I am in.

Comment: @Khan I want see your GetData  function how to call it in controller if you write seperate services then  inject services in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Givent that you've already had AreaGeneral routes defined as below:

```
public class AreaGeneralAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "AreaGeneral";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "AreaGeneral_default",
            "AreaGeneral/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "GetData", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

You can register that route in AreaB:

```
public class AreaBAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{ 
    public override string AreaName 
    { 
        get { return "AreaB"; } 
    } 
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "AreaB_Getdata",
            "AreaB/Home/Getdata",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "GetData" },
            new string[] { "areastest.Areas.AreaGeneral.Controllers" }).DataTokens["area"] = "AreaGeneral";

        context.MapRoute(
            "AreaB_default", 
            "AreaB/{controller}/{actio‌​n}/{id}", 
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

    }
}
```

so that user can navigate to `.../AreaB/Home/GetData` and view the page actually handled within AreaGeneral.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but dont I have to inherit the controller or something.

Comment: No, there would be no controller in AreaB.

Comment: And what about the url, will it change to .../AreaGeneral/GetData or stay as .../AreaB/GetData when accessing the GetData from AreaB

Comment: No, the url will stay the same. :)

Comment: thanks Bob, let me check today, then I will come back to you.

Comment: no its not working, my url is after areaGeneral registration is http://localhost:59518/AreaB/Home/Getdata, but getting 404 error. I registered the route as mentioned above by Bob Dust, but not working.

Comment: then you should register the route in `AreaB as /AreaB/Home/Getdata` instead of `areab/getdata`

Comment: Bob Dust, do you have working example of this please.

Comment: **Nope I just did but the same issue.**

Comment: **Here is my below code for area** `namespace areastest.Areas.AreaB{public class AreaBAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration{public override string AreaName{get{return "AreaB";}}public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {context.MapRoute("AreaB_default","AreaB/{controller}/{action}/{id}",new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });context.MapRoute("AreaB_Getdata","AreaB/Home/Getdata",new { controller = "Home", action = "GetData" },new string[] { "areastest.Areas.AreaGeneral.Controllers" }).DataTokens["area"] = "AreaGeneral";}}}`

Comment: The route `AreaB/Home/Getdata` should be placed above `AreaB/{controller}/{actio‌​n}/{id}`, @Khan

Comment: **Bob Dust**, this also is not working. can you place images of the working areas please, so I can see the configuration directly. yours if working right?

Comment: **Bob Dust**, wow!!!!!!!!!!, its working now, thanks alot for your kind help, really appreciate for sticking with me for a long time.

Comment: **Bob Dust**, Can I ask you one more thing, is it possible to register entire controller or entire area itself instead of registering individual actions.

Comment: I don't think so. For routing to other controller actions in other area, you need to specify exact action in `default` parameter of the route. So unfortunately, you have to deal with individual route in AreaB in case you want to dispatch those to AreaGeneral.

Answer (score 0):

I used angular services in different MVC areas for that I used following way

if  your project structure should be like following

```
  >ProjectName
  >Areas
       >AreaGeneral >controllername >GetData(function)
       >AreaA 
       >AreaB 
       >AreaC
```

if your services like

```
 app.service("yourService", ["$http",function ($http) {
    this.GetData= function () {       
    var c = $http({
        method: "post", 
        url:"../AreaGeneral/controllername/GetData",
        data: "{}",
         dataType: "json"
         });
    return c
} }])
```

if you are using inside  `AreaGeneral` then
 url `"../AreaGeneral/controllername/GetData"` ok for that

but when use different area like `AreaA`

`"../AreaGeneral/controllername/GetData"` its search inside the `AreaA`  so that you donot get result

Solution work for me like called function adding extra `../` as per root directory structure
this way

`"../../../AreaGeneral/controllername/GetData"`

then every time call getdata function it checks from root directory so this way you can use Getdata function in  any area

Hope this help you.

Comment: Ok. but how about the GetData view, do I have to copy the same view on each area where I want to use the same functionality. See my intention is that I want to use same view and same controller in different areas without re-writing the duplicate code, is it possible.

Comment: Can someone please let me know that how do I avail the same controller with its views inside another area without re-writing the view and controller.

Comment: use ng-include for access view from different area

Comment: any example Pravin for ng-include with areas, controllers and views.